# ASP.NET Core POST method always pending

Tags: http, post, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I'm trying to create a controller for an existing table in my database.

This is my Create method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ArticleCategoryViewModel model)
{
     ArticleCategory cat = new ArticleCategory { Code = model.Code, Name = model.Name, Description = model.Description, VATId = model.VATId };

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    _context.ArticleCategories.Add(cat);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewData["VATId"] = new SelectList(_context.VATs, "Id", "Percentage");
    return View(model);
}
```

This is the form from cshtml file for create:

```
<form asp-action="Create" class="form-horizontal bordered-group" role="form">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ArticleCategoryViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Code" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="VATId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="VATId" class ="form-control" asp-items="@((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["VATId"])"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Getting the information from database works, like get for index and details and edit, but when i try to post something like on create or after editing and i click submit button, its just pending. I tried every solution that i could find on the web but nothing works and i have no more ideas.

No logs are written, no error is thrown, nothing happens and i dont know why.

If i put a breakpoint inside the create method, it will not hit, so no debug.

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried without validateantiforgerytoken attribute

Comment: its same. what i noticed is when i try to post something my process memory is going up without stopping. so if i have 8 GB of ram it will rise to until all the memory is consumed..

Comment: strange behaviour. you should test this by creating a new empty asp.net-core project. if it s still same, there is no problem with your code and you will look for the application errors, else it means that you are able to write some server side codes which can be usefull bencmark tests

Comment: I created a new asp.net core project, created the database model, from db to code first. Created a new controller scaffold, did not change anything, still the same.

Comment: in fact, you could do this just with a controller and a view and a route mapping. you have maked tired yourself. anyway, i think your problem is application based, visual studio, dotnet or sql. let s wait for the experts opinions.  you may try this with the offical templates while waiting

Comment: @Vadik: 1) Ensure you are targeting .NET 4.5 *in your web.config*. 2) Create a [minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce locally.

Comment: Almost 2 years and no answers, I get this issue too, with Get requests also, seems to be temperamental, sometimes works okay, sometimes forever pending - Almost as if execution has paused but debugger has not been attached, so I cannot continue and the client request is forever waiting for a a server that will never continue